# Condition for a non-empty string

Tags: c#

I've been debating what seems like a small, trivial idea, but I am curious if there is more to it. Is there a difference between using the following two conditions to detect if a string is not empty? Are there any cases where this would return different results, or any subtleties that makes one a better choice?

```
str != ""
```

or

```
str.Length > 0
```

Comment: Why not use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(str);`?

Comment: That is a valid point to which I was not previously aware.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `str` is `null`, then `str != ""` will return `true`, but `str.Length > 0` will throw a [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx). Other than that, they are equivalent.

But there are also a few other methods might use, like [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) or [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).